# Dividing by square root of zero equals infinity?

Tags: fractions, infinity

So, my calculator app produced a result that doesn't seem correct to me. According to my calculator, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0}}=\infty$. By my understanding, $\sqrt{0}=0$ (since $0^2=0$). So, shouldn't $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0}}=\frac{1}{0}$ and therefore be undefined not equal to infinity?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The symbol $1/\sqrt{0}$ makes no sense.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your calculator app say about $1/0$, or $1/(+0.0)$? Sometimes, [computers will say $1/0 = +\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#Computer_arithmetic). This is often for reasons of convenience (since if it's undefined we might as well define it however we like). This means that on a computer, many useful facts like "$a + b = c + b$ implies $a = c$" are *not true*. The reason we say you can't divide by zero in actual abstract maths is because we like those useful facts to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be undefined. However, I should make you aware of the projectively extended real number system, where $+∞=-∞=∞$. $\frac{1}{0}$ is defined as $∞$. Here is a Wikipedia article about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line